# Javascript FileReader hangs at readyState 1 (using react-dropzone)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filereader, react-dropzone

Using the wonderful react-dropzone module I am attempting to read a dropped file with a FileReader before placing it in the redux store and sending it to the server. However, the events on the reader never trigger and I can't find out why not. Hope someone can help.

For curiosity, here's the `onDrop` handler I give the react-dropzone component:

```
const onDrop = (accepted, rejected) => {
        if(rejected.length > 0) {
            return console.error('Dropzone rejected:', rejected)
        }

        onChange(accepted[0])
    }
```

Here's my current onChange function:

```
const onChange = (file) => {

    file instanceof Blob === true
    file instanceof File === true

    var reader = new FileReader()

    reader.onload((event) => {
        console.log(event)
    })
    
    reader.onerror((event) => {
        console.log(event)
    })

    reader.readAsText(file)
}
```

Looking at the documentation and many posts on stackoverflow, the above should be right. The reader indeed changes its readyState to `1` and result to `""`. Yet, when I log the reader it never continues to readyState 2 nor does it ever trigger any events, also no error event.

Could there be somehting wrong with the file?

Comment: Why don't you show the code....

Comment: Is `onLoad` a function on the FileReader? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: updated. the rest of code is in the library

Comment: I realy recommend to undo your last edit and leave the question as it was. You would be surprised but others may do the same mistake and can benfit from your question.

Comment: @Sagivb.g it seems like General Grievance did it for me. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a [typo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload): should be `.onload` instead of `.onLoad`.

example from the docs (note the `=` sign):

```
reader.onload = function(event) {
    // The file's text will be printed here
    console.log(event.target.result)
  };
```

Comment: still no result... I'm modifying my post.

Comment: @PimHeijden I've updated my question, note the `=` sign

Comment: @PimHeijden This is the beauty of stack overflow, one is spending hours over a silly mistake, then post it on here. From now on, others with the same silly mistake will spend 2 minutes to find the answer on google (without the shame of posting it of course hehe). by the way you should accept an answer to mark it as closed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload), `onload` is a property of the FileReader:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = event => {
    console.log(event)
};

reader.readAsText(file);
```

Comment: still no result... I'm modifying my post.

Comment: It should be a property, not a function. Check the link.